# Como testar funções privadas?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

Tenho um controlador com algumas funções:

```
angular.module('teste.controllers')
.controller(TestCtrl, function($scope){
   var vm = this;

   vm.funcTest = function(){
    return 1 + 1;
   }

   function _testSoma2(){
     return 2 + 2;
   }
})
```

Agora no teste :

```
describe('Controllers: Timetable', function () {
 var TestCtrl;
 var $controller;
 var $scope;

 beforeEach(module('teste'));

 beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $injector){ 
   $controller = $controller;
   TestCtrl = $controller('TestCtrl', {
        '$scope': $scope
      });
   }));
   it('testar function privada.', function () {
      //como testar?
      //TestCtrl._testSoma2() ??
      expect(4).toBe(4);
   });
});
```

Como eu consigo realizar o teste na funçao _testSoma2() ?

nos vm eu consigo $scope.vm.funcTest() mas no _testSoma2() eu não consigo .

eu posso chamar essa função privada por diversas outras funçoes do scope, mas quero testar essa função separadamente.

Comment: Podes dar um exemplo mais claro? nesse exemplo essa função nunca é usada certo?

Comment: Exato, ela pode ser usada por uma função de um escopo. Mas quero testa-la separadamente.

Comment: Não é possível ter acesso à função separadamente, é uma limitação da linguagem. Você poderia ter um método público chamando a função e testar esse método, mas aí o método privado perde um pouco do propósito...